# Help with grub script to change grub conf

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, samba, nas

I'm afraid I know absolutely nothing about the formulation or syntax of a grub script so I was hoping to get some help here unless scripts in the /grub.d be coded in Python (I am familiar with Python)?

I feel that what I want to do is relatively simple though more complex and efficient options will also be detailed:

- Related to the script:
  I have a Raspberry Pi I am using successfully as a NAS server via samba. I am also looking to configure the RPi as a WOL server. I want to create a script that will force grub to look for the configuration file on the NAS (whether it be copied from the NAS to a more strict location, etc). Side note: I read something from 2009 about grub loading before the network service but I'd imagine some things have probably changed since then. My question then is, what protocols are allowed while grub is active? Is smb connection or ssh allowed?

So the order would be as such:

1) User changes grub conf file on NAS

2) Send WOL magic packet to boot

3) Grub loads (no timeout in case process takes too long)

4) Grub script loads grub file which replaces grub conf file to change default selection

The benefit of this method is that the user can change what OS is to be loaded even before the computer is booted. I would like to get more complicated by introducing some interaction over a network but I feel that by determining the feasibility of this most basic configuration, it will be evident whether is it worth it to try to proceed.

Comment: You can't use python script in early grub boot (init-top, init-local, etc.) because only binaries can be loaded. But you can load a python binary compiler which complies a python script into a binary. Then you can run the compiled binary. I looked for an example I had 3 or 4 years ago but could not find it on the net. It's probably still on the old laptop though. Basically I spent months on hooking into grub to boot off an mSata PCIe 1/2 card SSD of 18 GB that accelerated 100 GB Linux partition by hooking into Grub's init routines. I think something similar would be your solution.

Comment: Found the [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EnhanceIO). You want to use `pyinstaller` to compile your python scripts during boot in order to run them before the kernel is loaded.

Comment: Awesome! So my question then is: when the python script replaces the grub conf file, will it be able to change the default selection even though grub has already loaded - or does the script run prior to loading grub, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: My comment only addresses how to use Python Scrip in grub before kernel is loaded. For the rest of your problem you want to learn about grub-hooks which will take weeks if not months. This assuming I understand your problem correctly.